# Concurrent Neural Network - Enabling Currying

Tags: machine-learning, turing-machines, lambda-calculus, neural-networks

Currently, neural networks can be trained in a parallel fashion and I read a couple of very good research papers on it. I am trying to implement neural networks that can take concurrent input and compute the output.

For example, rather than directly taking an input vector $\\v=\begin{bmatrix}
    x_{1}\\
    x_{2}\\
    \vdots\\
    x_{n}
\end{bmatrix}\\$
and activating the neural network to produce certain output $\\y\\$, it should take a series of binary vectors that add up to the main vector.
For example let there be a normal neural network $\\f\\$ and a special kind of neural network $\\f_o\\$ with initial state $\\X_o\\$, an input vector $\\I=\begin{bmatrix}
    1\\
    3\\
    2
\end{bmatrix}\\$, rather than providing this as an input, neural network should take binary vectors like $\\\bar I= \{ \begin{bmatrix}
    0\\
    1\\
    0
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
    0\\
    1\\
    1
\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}
    1\\
    1\\
    1
\end{bmatrix} \} \\$ such that $\\I = \bar I_1+\bar I_2+\bar I_3\\$.

Rather than directly passing the decimal input vector to the neural network
$\\f(I) = y\\$
 I want to implement $\\f_o(\bar I_1)(\bar I_2)(\bar I_3) = y\\$. With every input vector, the state of function changes from $\\X_i \to X_{i+1}\\$ such that

1. $\\f_o\\$ allows orderless currying i.e. $\\f_o(\bar I_1)(\bar I_2)(\bar I_3) = f_o(\bar I_1)(\bar I_3)(\bar I_2) = f_o(\bar I_3)(\bar I_2)(\bar I_1) = ...\\$
2. The only thing that changes the state of neural network/machine is "1" values of the input vector i.e. $\\f_o([1]) : X_i \to X_{i+1}\\$ and $\\f_o([0]) : X_i \to X_{i}\\$
3. And statement 2 said, any integer vector $\\v\\$ could be decomposed in vectors $\\\geq \max(v)\\$

   **How can this be implemented? Should I develop a FSM and Neural Network hybrid? Are there current alternatives for the same? I am afraid if I know all the important keywords, please feel free to edit the tags**
   Kindly provide me some direction for the same. 
    I have completed significant parts of the project but this area is something I am currently working on. I hope the community could provide me support.
   **Thanks in advance**